# Bing Translate Android Set Language

Tags: android, translation, bing-api

My App uses the Bing Translate API .
   Now i want to set the target language like here:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

        Translate.setClientId("hidden");
        Translate.setClientSecret("hidden");


        try {
            String translatedText = Translate.execute(textToTranslate,  Language.ENGLISH/* <----Target Language */);
            b.setText(translatedText);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(this,"Fail!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        }
    }
```

But the Target Language should be a string .
When i am using a string i got the error that i cant use a string here.
Could anybody help me , please ?

Sammy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The target language parameter is not a `String`. `Language` is an enum class. You can use it just as you have it in the code you've posted, or you can call `Language.valueOf()` to get the appropriate value to pass to the `execute()` method.

For example:

```
String translatedText = Translate.execute(textToTranslate, Language.valueOf("ENGLISH"));
```

Comment: Thanks. So let us say  Language.fromString(string) has the value ENGLISH .Will it have the same effect like Language.ENGLISH? P.S. I would  vote up if I were able to do so.

Comment: No problem. Btw, I think I answered your comment rather obliquely. To be clear, yes, they will both have the same effect. Cheers!

Comment: Now I tried to run the App .First with this : Language.ENGLISH and then LANGUAGE.fromString(string) and they dont have the same effects

Comment: i received java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: Are you sure `b` isn't null?

Comment: @FabianSawischa Oh, jeez, sorry! It's been a while since I used that. I forgot the `fromString()` method takes a two-letter language code, like `en`. Glad you got it figured out! I correct my answer when I get a minute later. Cheers!

Comment: Ah thanks now i know where I can use the language code